# is SpriteBodyComponent/PositionBodyComponent deprecated from latest flame-forge2d version

Tags: flame, forge2d

while looking for documentation, I'm really confused, since in https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.0.0/components.html?highlight=bodycomponent#spritebodycomponent SpriteBodyComponent is still using, but in
flame_forge2d: 0.12.3
flame: 1.4.0
I can't find this SpriteBodyComponent.

Because Im following a tutorial and the code looks like this:

```
    class Ball extends SpriteBodyComponent {
        ...
    }
```

But since I can not find SpriteBodyComponent, my code is like this:

```
class Ball extends BodyComponent{
    ...
}
```

And then tutorial is using `Vector2 size` from SpriteBodyComponent, and I have no idea what I can do.. since in official documentation SpriteBodyComponent still exists, but what I find from flame flame package is `SpriteComponent` but what I want to find should be from flame_forge2d something like SpriteBodyComponent, and if I use such code:

```
class Ball extends SpriteBodyComponent{
   ...
}
```

I got error `Mixin can only be applied to class.` and I can not find it in flame-forge2d package either.

thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the documentation for Flame `1.0.0`, the latest version currently is `1.4.0` as you have found out, you can change version of the docs in the upper right corner.

These are the latest `flame_forge2d` docs:
https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.4.0/flame_forge2d/forge2d.html

But to answer your question, yes, `SpriteBodyComponent` has been deprecated.
Now instead you add a `SpriteComponent` as a child to a `BodyComponent`, for example like this:

```dart
class Pizza extends BodyComponent {
  final Vector2 position;
  final Vector2 size;

  Pizza(
    this.position,
    this.size,
  );

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    final sprite = await gameRef.loadSprite('pizza.png');
    renderBody = false;
    add(
      SpriteComponent(
        sprite: sprite,
        size: size,
        anchor: Anchor.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Body createBody() {
    // Create your body
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi spydon, thank you again for your introduction to flame world, now at least I learned more about how to read documentation:) have a good night